# Move iframe to the right or shift content inside iframe to the left

Tags: javascript, html, css, iframe

I have this annoying black strip on the left and right side of my video. It took a long time to reduce the size of it to the thin strip it is now, but my video cropping skills stopped there.

To get rid of the line on the right side of the video I place the video on another web page and inserted an iframe on the parent page for viewing.

It is a compromise, but it works. by adjusting the width of the iframe to a few pixels less than the width of the video, the black line (border) does not show on the right.

That leaves the left side of the page.

I have tried placing a 2 pixel wide x 260 pixel tall jpg to cover the black line but I guess you can't place a pic on top of a vid.

Then I tried moving the iframe to the right by a few pixels so it will only show me the part of the vid I want to see.

using ...

```
<iframe onload="window.frames.scrollTo(300,300)" src="vid2.php" width=375 height=260 frameborder=0 scrolling=no name="vframe">
```

but that didn't do anything

and in the header:

```
<style type='text/css'>

#innerdiv {
position:absolute;
top:0px;
left:2px;
width:375px;
height:260px;
}
</style>
```

and in the body

```
<iframe id="innerdiv" src="vid2.php" width=375 height=260 frameborder=0 scrolling=no name="vframe">
```

and all that does is repositions the iframe on the parent page.

What i want to do is move the iframe *over to the right of the page it encases*  by like 3 pixels.

I tried to move the vid object to the left (-3px) but I guess once you hit the left side, that is as far as you can go.

Comment: if you have access to the video page, you need to add the styles in that page. If not, you can't alter that iframe's content. However, it's possible to place an image on top of it, just add z-index to both elements (both iframe and image)

Comment: thanks ... for anyone else: <head> <style type='text/css'>
        .div_exp1
        {
            border: 0;
            background-color: #ffffff;
            position: absolute;
            z-index: 100;
            height: 260px;
            width: 2px;
        } </style></head> <body>   <div> <div class="div_exp1" id="div1">
            <img src="images/strip.jpg">
        </div> </div> </body>  places it over the vid